# Last version of drools kie workbench

Tags: drools, workbench, kie

Is there a documentation of  the last version of drools kie workbench ?
I can not test my rules.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is...very easy to find on the website [Drools latest version documentation](http://drools.org/learn/documentation.html)